# what is $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}^* } \chi(n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Given a no trivial homomorphism $\chi$ from $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}^*$ to $\mathbb{C}^*$, what is $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}^* } \chi(n)$? is it $0$? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\chi:(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\ast\to\Bbb C^\ast$ is not trivial, then there exists $m\in(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\ast$ such that $\chi(m)\neq 1$.
We have
\begin{align}
\chi(m)\sum_{n \in (\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\ast }\chi(n)
&=\sum_{n \in (\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\ast }\chi(mn)\\
&=\sum_{n \in (\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\ast }\chi(n)
\end{align}
hence
$$(\chi(m)-1)\sum_{n \in (\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\ast }\chi(n)$$
from which
$$\sum_{n \in (\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\ast }\chi(n)=0$$